# Web page finished loading before all images are completed

Tags: php, html, apache

After the release of the new web site I've developed I have a strange case with the images on the site.

It seems like the page is finished loading before all images are completed.

The images is located on another server using samba to share the images. Could this connection be to slow?

On my development server this worked out all fine.

Could this be some settings in Apache or PHP?

Comment: Do the images ever finish loading? Maybe file path incorrect?
Also are you basing loaded on your browser saying 'Done'?

Comment: If you are using firefox get the addon 'Web Developer' and use the tool 'Find Broken Images'

Comment: You can use firebug, fiddler, httpanalyzer to check for invalid/incorrect paths.

Comment: The page is located here: http://www.ingenioren.no/polygonas
Only half the image i shown, so the path is ok.

Comment: All the images seem to load for me. Here's the results of my firebug's new pannel
[http://pastebin.com/ma7f7c34](http://pastebin.com/ma7f7c34)

Comment: side note: I am getting this in the console: [cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem on my own.

The images was located on an external server. When copying the images locally, the problem seem to disappear. Mabye the share between the servers was not fast enought?

Thanks for alle answers!

Answer (score 0):

Html code is loaded when you visit a web page. The heavy resource are slower to be loaded.

One tip to know is to *preload* image by using a css style you can find [a description here (Preloading Images With CSS)](http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol6/css_no18.htm) or [CSS Throwdown: Preload Images without JavaScript](http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/07/22/css-throwdown-preload-images-without-javascript/)

The difference between the localhost behavior and the server behavior is caused by the bandwidth...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue before when an image I exported got "slighty corrupted". Try re-exporting the image to see if it resolves the issue (i.e. edit it in your preferred image editor and do a "save as" - saving it to a different location. Then replace your broken image with the new one).